# /Date(1533668400000)/ Format date in correct sequence In React

Tags: reactjs, datetime

My react code for displaying information is as follows
My data is being displayed correctly
The issue is that the date's are not being displayed properly
Date are being displayed as /Date(1533668400000)/
The data base entry is 2018-08-08 00:00:00.000
I have added scrrenshots so that it is easy to understand

```
 class BorrowHistoryGridRow extends React.Component
 {
     constructor(props)
     {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items:this.props.items}
     }
     render()
     { 
         return (
                 <tr>
                      <td>{this.props.item.bName}</td>
                      <td>{this.props.item.cName}</td>
                      <td>{this.props.item.bhBorrowDate}</td>
                      <td>{this.props.item.bhReturnDate}</td>
                 </tr>
              );
     }
  }
```

[image: pictures shows you my output page here it can be seen than date is not being displayed correctly]

[image: In the second picture you can see my sql database entry there the date is right]

Comment: your date is probably saved to db in an improper / specific format. It is displayed correctly in you db client but it is probably a string. try `console.log(this.props.item.bhBorrowDate, typeof this.props.item.bhBorrowDate)` before your return in your render to see what your prop actually look like.

Comment: Depending on what you see from that we will be able to parse it properly.

Comment: @MathieuK. my console shows /Date(1533668400000)/ string.....

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function that will solve your displaying problem

```
<td>{this.getDate(this.props.item.bhBorrowDate)}</td>
```

and the function would return string that is formated date that you could print.

```
getDate = (x) => {      
  const a = x;
  const b = Number(a.slice(6, a.length - 2));
  const c = new Date(b);
  return c.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

If you do not like this typoe of data formatting, you can easily use some other native to JavaScript, or use moment.js